# How to use 'AS' in cakephp 4 query?

Tags: php, cakephp

How to add AS in cake php query?

```
$table = $this
->find()
->select(['id', 'fname AS first_name'])
```

When i run it
"check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS "

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple try:

```
$this
->find()
->select(['id'])
->select(['fname' => 'first_name']); // SELECT first_name AS fname
```

and read:

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data